# How to distinguish Julian and Gregorian calendars in Latin?

Tags: idiom, time, calendarium

In some contexts it is important to express whether a given date (for example October 25 and November 7 in 1917) is according to the Julian or the Gregorian calendar.
Are there established Latin phrases for this?
For example, should I say *Nonis Aprilibus anno MCMX ad calendarium Iulianum/Gregorianum*?
Latin was in wider use when both calendars were used at the same time, so I assume there was an idiom for this purpose.

Comment: I've never come across this, and wonder if there was need enough for standard phrases? For what it's worth in interest, in English contemporary with the change the two systems were simply referred to by, for example, the historian of Rome Edward Gibbon, as 'O.S.' (_Old Style_, i.e. Julian) and 'N.S.' (_New Style_).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google conjures up a good number of old books with "stylus (or stilus) vetus" and "stylus (stilus) novus".

Comment: It might be because Google personalizes search results, but I could not find a single hit for "stylus novus" used in a Latin text to refer to the choice of calendar. I found [one hit](http://pau.krakow.pl/Elementa/tomy/Elementa_IV_1961.pdf) for "stylus vetus". It is reasonable to expect that if these Latin phrases are used with German and some other languages, then it would be applicable in Latin as well. There were very few hits with *stilus*, too. Did you mean these Latin phrases used within other languages, or actual fully Latin documents using these phrases?

Comment: Here is an example in a Latin context. The author is a well-known astronomer, so someone who knows what he is talking about: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6k73c__jWo0C&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=%22stylus+vetus%22&source=bl&ots=kI_QmPCACK&sig=7cb3AdySe5AIBuJIUwgbT98pVuU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTipr-1_TVAhXFB8AKHSYuDUUQ6AEIRjAI#v=onepage&q=%22stylus%20vetus%22&f=false

Comment: Thanks! For the benefit of those who cannot or do not want to follow the link, here is a telling passage: *Notandum quod stylus vetus idem fit ac priscum Calendarium Julianum: sed stylus novus vel Gregorianus ante annum 1700. currentem, dies decem plus plusquam vetus numerabat...*

Answer (score 1):

Whatever it is that you intend to write, and if you need to make the distinction, it has obviously to be set at a time after the adoption of the Gregorian calendar. As I mentioned in a comment on the question, the two systems after the change were simply referred to as 'O.S.' (*Old Style*, i.e. Julian) and 'N.S.' (*New Style*) in English writings.

In adopting those references, a satisfactory word would be *ratio*, which I suggest is preferable to either *modus* or *genus*. I should myself choose any of these before *stilus*, although in classical times the word was sometimes actually used with a secondary meaning similar to that sought here — but that's just a personal preference. In the choice of adjectives there are various alternatives — for instance *prior* and *vetus*,  *recens*,*novus* and perhaps *infimus*, none of which seems controversial — though one might just as comfortably (and more clearly) use *Julianus* and *Gregorianus* instead of 'old' and 'new'.

In a later context, in times when it has/had become customary to use simple ordinals for the days of the month in English,  it's not really appropriate to use the method of expressing dates from classical times. By the time the Gregorian system had been adopted across Europe, if not earlier, the old Ides of March, for example, would generally be written in correspondence as something like *dies XV mensis Martialis A.D.MDCCLXXVII*.